# SP 2010 CSOM Javascript: serverRelativeUrl fails

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have a custom html and javascript file housed within a document library of a subsite:
`http://teamsite/project/testing%20site/shared%20documents/test.html`
and

```
http://teamsite/project/testing%20site/shared%20documents/test.js




function testContext(){
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://teamsite/projects/testing%20site/");
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();

clientContext.load(collList);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onWin), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));

function onWin(){alert("Success");}
function onFail(){ alert("Fail");}
```

Everytime I execute the above I get this error:

> SCRIPT5022: Sys.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>   Parameter name: serverRelativeUrl 
>   sp.runtime.js, line 2 character 38258

I've tried several different methods to get CSOM to work in this instance and everytime I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor `SP.ClientContext(serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl)` expects `serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl` to be the server-relative URL that:

- starts with `/`
- or a full URL that starts with `http://` or `https://`

in SharePoint **2013**.

In SharePoint **2010** it could be only the server-relative URL that starts with `/`.

---

As an alternative you could utilize:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

to get the *current* client context of the client-side object model (CSOM) runtime

Comment: This doesn't appear to work because the javascript lives outside of webparts.

Code:

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oWebsite = ctx.get_web();
this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
clientContext.load(collList);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onWin), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));

Throws 2x errors:
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'webServerRelativeUrl': object is null or undefined 

SCRIPT5022: Sys.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
Parameter name: serverRelativeUrl

Comment: So assuming the HTML and Javascript are executing out of site/sitename/shareddocuments and the list I want to access is in site/sitename I have attempted absolute URL reference 'http://site/sitename' (fails) and the relative URLs '../' and 'site/sitename' and '../.' and all fail.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
```

Use relative Url in site url

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185009(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Per my example I assume you mean: siteUrl = 'projects/testing%20site' which returns the same error.

Comment: As in example start your url with "/"

Comment: It appears to have executed but now throws the error:

"Request failed. The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your browser's Back button to try your operation again.
undefined."

Comment: Are you calling this from another site collection or from same site collection.

Comment: If you turn off the Web Page Security Validation, the security goes away.

Manage Web Application----> Select the web application---Click on General Settings(under the ribbon) and turn off the Web Page Security Validation.

Comment: Same site collection.
http://project/testing%20site/shareddocuments/test.html
trying to access the lists within http://project/testing%20site/