# JSOM SP.ClientContext returning Error

Tags: 2013, javascript, jsom

When I attempt to do

```
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("https://siteurl");
    var item = ctx
                .get_web()
                .get_lists()
                .getByTitle("Folder")
                .getItemById(1);
    item.breakRoleInheritance(false, true);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        ...
    });
```

I receive the following error from the first line

`Uncaught Error: Sys.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.`

I tried following this [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/116519/34737) but the problem still occurs.

Edit: If I do

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("/")
```

I get the error

```
_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery 403 (FORBIDDEN)
Cannot read property 'requestUnexpectedResponseWithStatus' of undefined
```

when the code is executed.

Comment: is above code running on same server url which you are specifying in constructor... ? are you getting error directly when above line is executed  ?

Comment: @SiddharthVaghasia Yes, it's the same server url. It happens directly when I run the first line.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/154691/20615

Comment: Can you post here your url you are passing to the `ClientContext` constructor?

Comment: @wjervis there is no nested function, it's happening simply from even doing it within the console

@Kai it's an internal URL basically something in the gist of `https://subdomain.domain.com` (doing https and http doesn't work. It's not under a /sites/ like typical websites provided by our admins.

Comment: Added a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue was for that for 2013, it uses the same files but different location.

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
```

I had them all pointing to `/_layouts/...` instead of `/_layouts/15/...`